# How do you compensate for a varying DC offset when using a wheatstone bridge?

Tags: analog, wheatstone-bridge, dc-offset

### Background

I have a sensitive magnetic sensor that is packaged as a wheatstone bridge with a 20k
device resistance. I am using it to measure the rotation of a magnet. It is possible to calibrate out the offset voltage by applying a voltage to Vref of the instrumentation amplifier when the offset is constant (like with a with a strain gauge). However, the offset of the magnetic sensor can vary depending on the orientation in the earths magnetic field. Here is an example with two sensors.

Green & Yellow = Sensor 1

Pink & Blue = Sensor 2

[image: scope screenshot of magnetic sensor offset]

Here are the same two devices rotated by 90 degrees. The DC offset changes from 20-40mV. Also note sensor 1 has a difference of 27mV between differential pairs and sensor two has a difference of 9mv.

[image: scope screenshot of magnetic sensor offset rotated]

Here is a screenshot of the magnet rotating which produces a ~50mV sine wave

[image: magnet producing a sine wave]

### Problem

I have built a circuit using the [INA321](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina321.pdf?ts=1692199293055&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FINA321), but when the offset gets too large the opamp rails and produces clipped output. Even when the output is not clipped, the large DC offset change in the output makes it hard to count zero crossings which is my end goal.

[image: INA321 simulation]

### Question

How can I compensate for the offset variance due to device differences and the earths magnetic field?

Using a high pass filter is not an option because I need to be able to measure very slow frequency. My power budget is also very limited so this needs to be done without the use of a microcontroller.

Comment: You might be surprised at how low power a microcontroller can be. Your opamps are using 2mW, you can operate many microcontrollers at >20x less power

Comment: Also, a "DC offset change" isn't really "DC" if it keeps changing. If you want to do this passively, anything you do is basically going to be some sort of high pass filter, just with a longer time-scale. When you say "very slow frequency", how slow exactly?

Comment: Have you tried making the existing offset section (shown as U1) variable?

Comment: @BeB00 I will be duty cycling whatever op-amps I end up using to reduce power. The INA321 uses 40μA per channel and I should be able to reduce that depending on my duty cycle frequency. Regarding the changing DC offset, it only changes when the device is moved or from part to part. It will be stationary when operating, but I need to account for the case where a user moves it from time to time.

Comment: @Nedd Yes, the simulation showing the clipping is with a Vref of 100mv. I can't go lower than that.

Comment: @Nabil apologies, I missed that in your question, your schematic says INA332. It sounds like you only want the offset to change (i.e. be "recalibrated") under certain external conditions - without a microcontroller or a button for the user to press, I'm not sure how it would be logically possible to implement that, other than having a high pass filter

Comment: @Nabil even with the INA321, you still have the OPA335 using 1mW, vs an mcu using <100uW. You can also duty cycle the mcu.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to trim the offset of a wheatstone bridge, then use the circuit below, load the NL resistors (either the pull up or pull down, but not both) to compensate the offset, usually start with a high value like 1meg and then work down.

[image: schematic]

As far as the instrumentation amp circuit, it would be better if you use a full balanced instrumentation amplifier.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This solution seems to be for static DC offset, correct? I need to account for changing DC offsets. I will look into a full balanced INA

Comment: If you need a changeable DC offset then a current DAC could do the job at the expense of some added noise another way to do this is to use a PGA instrumentation app that has multiple gains